# Scan a filename and extract a three digit character after a delimiter

Tags: excel, vba

I having some trouble with Excel VBA Macros. Basically I need to extract a sheet number from a file name and the naming convention is not always followed. For example:

```
(Plant Number - Index Letter - Drawing Number - Sheet Number) 
000-M-40324-002
3-PS-17345-001
010-S-59239-
10-K6-59235-2M
012-J-59423-103-A
```

The number I need to get is mostly always the last three digits in the name but not always and sometimes it's moved out by more than the expected dashes.

I have tried a VBA function. but my programming skills are lacking now.

Script:

```
Public Function GetWSheetNumber(s As String) As String
Dim v As String
For i = 1 To Len(s)
    ch = Mid(s, i, 1)
    If IsNumeric(ch) Then
        v = v & ch
    Else
        v = v & " "
    End If
Next i

v = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(v)

ary = Split(v, " ")
For Each a In ary
    If Len(a) = 3 Then
        GetWSheetNumber = a
        Exit Function
    End If
Next a

GetWSheetNumber = ""
End Function
```

It is always the last three numbers. There is always a hyphen to separate the values. The expected results from my sample are as follows:

```
000-M-40324-002     - 002
3-PS-17345-001       - 001
010-S-59239-           - No Value
10-K6-59235-2M      - No Value
012-J-59423-103-A  - 103
```

Comment: Do you mean always the last 3 digits wherever they occur? Will they always be separated by a hyphen? What are expected results of your sample?

Comment: See Updated Post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work, little bit other conception than Yours:

```
Public Function nameconv(s As String) As String

Dim ctr As Long
Dim i As Long

If Not IsNumeric(Right(s, 1)) Then
    nameconv = "Naming convention is not followed"
Else

    For i = 1 To Len(s)

        If IsNumeric(Mid(s, Len(s) - i + 1, 1)) Then 'Or CLng(Mid(s, Len(s) - i, 1)) = 0 Then
            ctr = ctr + 1
            'If ctr > 3 Then

            'End If
        Else

            If IsNumeric(Right(s, i - 1)) And ctr = 3 Then
                nameconv = CStr(Right(s, 3))
                Exit For
            Else
                nameconv = "Naming convention is not followed"
                Exit For
            End If
        End If

    Next

End If

End Function

Sub test()

MsgBox nameconv("000-M-40324-002")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Split` is a good approach. The OP just used it in the wrong context, and much later than it should have been for full benefit.

```
Public Function GetWSheetNumber(ByVal s As String) As String
Dim parsedString As Variant  ' You called this "ary" in your original code
    parsedString = Split(s, "-") ' Get straight to the heart of the problem!

    GetWSheetNumber = "Invalid format" '<-- default bad answer just in case you want to do additional checking!

Dim stringToCheck As String
    stringToCheck = parsedString(UBound(parsedString))
    If Len(stringToCheck) = 3 And IsNumeric(stringToCheck) Then
        GetWSheetNumber = stringToCheck
    Else
        GetWSheetNumber = "Invalid format: " & stringToCheck '<-- tailored bad answer
    End If
End Function
```

Test this using:

```
Private Sub TestGetNumber()
    Debug.Print GetWSheetNumber("000-M-40324-002")
    Debug.Print GetWSheetNumber("3-PS-17345-001")
    Debug.Print GetWSheetNumber("010-S-59239-")
    Debug.Print GetWSheetNumber("10-K6-59235-2M")
    Debug.Print GetWSheetNumber("012-J-59423-103-A")
End Sub
```

We can get smarter and check for another potentially valid case (the OP's last example). In order to do this efficiently (DRY) we move the checking to its own routine.

```
Public Function GetWSheetNumber2(ByVal s As String) As String
Dim parsedString As Variant  ' You called this "ary" in your original code
    parsedString = Split(s, "-") ' Get straight to the heart of the problem!

    GetWSheetNumber2 = "Invalid format" '<-- default bad answer just in case you want to do additional checking!

Dim stringToCheck As String
    stringToCheck = parsedString(UBound(parsedString))
    If CheckString(stringToCheck) Then
        GetWSheetNumber2 = stringToCheck
    Else
        GetWSheetNumber2 = "Invalid format: " & stringToCheck ' <-- prepare for bad result based on previous check before setting new check
        stringToCheck = parsedString(UBound(parsedString) - 1)
        If CheckString(stringToCheck) Then GetWSheetNumber2 = stringToCheck
    End If

End Function

Private Function CheckString(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
    CheckString = (Len(s) = 3 And IsNumeric(s))
End Function
```

Test this using:

```
Private Sub TestGetNumber2()
    Debug.Print GetWSheetNumber2("000-M-40324-002")
    Debug.Print GetWSheetNumber2("3-PS-17345-001")
    Debug.Print GetWSheetNumber2("010-S-59239-")
    Debug.Print GetWSheetNumber2("10-K6-59235-2M")
    Debug.Print GetWSheetNumber2("012-J-59423-103-A")
End Sub
```

Two key notes:

- I have not set any checks on the array to make sure there is more
  than one element (e.g. a string with no "-" will cause an out of
  bounds error).
- The OP could iterate backwards through the array to check all components
  and exit the loop/function when a valid string is found. My code
  above is based on only doing two checks - after all we don't want to
  be too loose with our formats!

Comment: Thanks, AJD for the reply. Your solution did work but did return a variety of error messages. This made it harder to map the ones that don't conform to the naming convention as i couldn't apply a general rule to them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @GordonCleary: The good old fashioned data cleansing problem! OK - I could only test it on the data you provided.